# Error using dplyr package in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am using the below code to extract the summary of data with respect to column x by counting the values in column x from the dataset unique_data and arranging the count values in descending order.

```
unique_data %>%
group_by(x) %>%
arrange(desc(count(x)))
```

But, when I execute the above code i am getting the error message as below,

> Error: no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "character"

Kindly, let me know as what is going wrong in my code. For your information the column x is of character data type.

Regards,
Mohan

Comment: Without showing a reproducible example, it is not clear where you got the error.  One problem would be wrapping `count(x)` with `desc` (but we can't test)

Comment: @akrun Kindly find the below example,  ID  sdf  fgh  sdf  sdf  fgf  So, now I need to count the distinct values from my ID column. So, i should get the output as,  sdf  3  fgh  2

Comment: I think the `count` with `arrange` is the problem.  Perhaps `unique_data %>% group_by(x) %>% count(x) %>% arrange(desc(n))`  Or it can be shortened to `count(unique_data, x) %>% arrange(desc(n))`

Comment: side note, I like `arrange(-n)` for reversing order, it's nice and clean

Comment: @akrun Thank you for your help... It worked...

Comment: Thanks @NathanDay for the details..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason is the wrapping of `arrange` on `count`.  We need to do this separately.  If we use the same code as in the OP's post, just split up the `count` and `arrange` step in two separate pipes.  The output of `count` is a frequency column 'n' (by default), which we `arrange` in descending (`desc`) order.

```
unique_data %>% 
          group_by(x) %>% 
          count(x) %>%
          arrange(desc(n))
```

also the `group_by` is not needed.  According to the `?count` documentation

> tally is a convenient wrapper for summarise that will either call n or
>   sum(n) depending on whether you're tallying for the first time, or
>   re-tallying. count() is similar, but also does the group_by for you.

So based on that, we can just do

```
count(unique_data, x) %>%
          arrange(desc(n))
```